# Create a file with students and view the information from the students that have more average grade from 5 and the average grade from each student

Tags: java

```
//Create the file Alumns.txt where we have a group of students with their last names, names and average grade, separed by “,” and view the information from the students that have more average grade from 5 and the average grade from each student.

//We have the file Alumns.txt with the content:
```

// Remo Ramirez, Noelia, 6, Jimenez Santos, Carlos, 4, Perez Gomez, Fernando, 7, Hamilton Bryan, Taylor, 3, Gutierrez Mendoza, Jose, 8, Garcia Reyes, Maria, 6, Marchante Mendez, Luna, 3, Delgado Mendez, Angel, 10.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        File fichero = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        Scanner sc = null;
        double [] notas = new double [6];
```

File Alumnos.txt

```
        fichero = new File ("Alumnos.txt");
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String texto2 = br.readLine();
            fr = new FileReader(fichero);
            sc = new Scanner(fichero);
            String texto = sc.nextLine();
            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(texto2, ",");
```

//I have tryed with Scanner and BufferedReader and the 'notas' (numbers) are each 3 tokens.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
                tokens.nextToken();
                tokens.nextToken();
                notas[i] = (double)Double.parseDouble(tokens.nextToken());
                System.out.println("Nota: "+notas[i]);
                if (notas [i]>5) {
                    System.out.println("Pass the grade 5: "+tokens.nextToken());
                }
            }
//I catch the exceptions here:

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have this file grades.csv

```
Remo Ramirez,Noelia,6
Jimenez Santos,Carlos,4
Perez Gomez,Fernando,7
Hamilton Bryan,Taylor,3
Gutierrez Mendoza,Jose,8
Garcia Reyes,Maria,6
Marchante Mendez,Luna,3
Delgado Mendez,Angel,10
```

We can write this method for parsing through it and printing only the students having an average grade better than 5.

```
public static void printGradesBetterThanFive() throws IOException {

        //Create a file object, path to the file might differ in your case.
        File grades = new File("grades.csv");
        if (grades.isFile()) {

            //Create a BufferedReader, taking in a FileReader with our File as an argument
            BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(grades));

            //Parse through each line in the file until we reach the end of it
            String line;
            while ((line = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {

                //Create an array containing values from each line, separated by commas.
                String[] lineData = line.split(",");

                //If the last value (the grade) is more than 5, print it.
                if (Integer.parseInt(lineData[2]) > 5) {
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lineData));
                }
            }
            csvReader.close();
        }
    }
```

Your question is a bit vague, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Might want to add a try/catch for a NumberFormatException on the Integer.parseInt-method.